# State whether or not the relation on the set of reals is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric or transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

State whether or not the relation on the set of real numbers is reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric or transitive.

$$R= \{(x,y)\mid x=1\text{ or }y=1\}$$

This is what I have done up to now, not sure if I am right though.

> i) it is reflexive.
>
> for any arbitrary $x\in R$; $(x,x)\in R$
>
> $x=1$ or $x=1$
>
> ii) it is symmetric
>
> since if $x=1$ or $y=1$ then $y=1$ or $x=1$
>
> iii) it is not antisymmetric
>
> counterexample.
>
> $(1,5)\in R$ and $(5,1)\in R$
>
> but $x\ne y$
>
> IV) it is not transitive.
>
> counterexample:
>
> $(7,1)\in R$ and $(1,7)\in R$
>
> But $(7,7)\notin R$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Usually questions that show no research effort get shunned, downvoted, and/or deleted. If you were to add your thoughts and efforts on the question as an additional paragraph this would probably garner greater response. The site ideal formula for a great question is roughly described [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I think it is reflexive, symmetric but not anti-symmetric and not transitive.

Comment: User2976636: You will want to click edit on your post, and then add this comment, and anything else you have to say on the issue (the more the better if it is relevant). You might want to include why you think this. You can edit your post as often as you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation is clearly **not** reflexive: $\langle 2,2\rangle\notin R$. In fact, the only pair $\langle x,x\rangle$ that **is** in $R$ is $\langle 1,1\rangle$.

It is symmetric; your explanation isn’t very clear, but I suspect that you have the right idea. Here’s a more complete explanation:

> Suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$; then either $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle 1,y\rangle$, or $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,1\rangle$. If $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle 1,y\rangle$, then $\langle y,x\rangle=\langle y,1\rangle\in R$, and if $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,1\rangle$, then $\langle y,x\rangle=\langle 1,x\rangle\in R$, so in all cases $\langle y,x\rangle\in R$, and $R$ is therefore symmetric.

Your argument that $R$ is not antisymmetric is basically right, though you really ought to conclude with $1\ne 5$ rather than with $x\ne y$. Your argument that $R$ is not transitive is fine. (Note that in the latter you observed that $\langle 7,7\rangle\notin R$: this should immediately tell you that $R$ is not reflexive.)

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up for me, I am new with discrete mathematics and it is not easy.

Comment: @user2976636: You’re welcome. You seem to be off to a fairly good start with it.